# Vaadin - ConcurrentModificationException while adding component to VerticalLayout

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

In **Vaadin 7.7.10** I have **VerticalLayout** and couple of components (each consisting from more components inside). I am trying to add them via **.addComponent()** function, but one of them is causing an error:

```
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:953)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:886)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1067)[:1.7.0_79]
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.attach(AbstractClientConnector.java:623)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.attach(AbstractComponent.java:684)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:587)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractOrderedLayout.addComponent(AbstractOrderedLayout.java:97)
```

Prior to this error, I also see couple of Vaadin server warnings:

```
Tried to unregister XY (num) which is not registered
```

However, it only happens first time the page is displayed after the server starts. When I try again, everything works fine.

It looks like I am lacking some method that properly initialize the component after being created for the first time - a method, that is being called automatically next time the wrapping **View** is loaded. But so far I have no idea what it should be?

Comment: Please show the relevant code, our wizard is just out of the office

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find the exact source of my error, but I found a way how to avoid it. What helped was to explicitly call `.setValue()` method to every `Field` inside the component prior to adding via `.addComponent()` method.